# How to place an image inside Text using CSS3?

Tags: html, css

I want to change the appearance of text using a mask on mouse hover. I thought image-mask would be the right way to do this but I can not get it to work. My goal is to have images inside of text.

HTML:

```
<div id="BEN">BEN</div>
```

​
CSS:

```
#ben {
    font-family: 'Arial';
    font-size: 72px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    float: right;
    line-height:90px;
    font-weight:bold;

}
#ben:hover {
-webkit-mask-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/u/16640285/mask.jpg);
-o-mask-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/u/16640285/mask.jpg);
-moz-mask-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/u/16640285/mask.jpg);
mask-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/u/16640285/mask.jpg);
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tKE6N/3/

Comment: Note that CSS IDs are case-sensitive :)

Comment: thanks, but still I can't see image mask working

Comment: Are you expecting to see the image .jpg file inside the large letters? Also, update your jsFiddle with correct ID case-style, they should not be different.

Comment: yes I was expecting that, is that how image-mask is meant to work?

Comment: `mask-image` requires an image with transparent or semi-transparent pixels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per your Question Title and more importantly your comment of expecting the image inside of the text letters, you need to use CSS3 `background-clip` to accomplish this, not `mask-image`.

Here's a webkit [**tutorial**](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/12/12/experiments-with-background-clip-text/) to point you in the right direction.

Play with it (Chrome or Safari) with this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f2Bg3/).

---

For `background-clip` **values**, [**Firefox**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-clip) does not support `text` but supports `border-box`, `padding-box`, and `content-box`. For this reason the demo will not work in Firefox v13.0.1 but v14 is expected to have this functionality.

Workaround is to use SVG method as illustrated [**HERE**](http://www.myadzel.ru/tests/html/text-background/).

Comment: Thanks, I have followed all your instructions but can not see why this simple code is not working: http://jsfiddle.net/tKE6N/5/

Comment: Change `rgba(0,0,0,1)` to `rgba(0,0,0,0.5)` since the last value represents alpha-transparency which allows you to see the background image under the font color. For no mixed-in font color, use `rgba(0,0,0,0)`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you declared your div with `<div id="BEN">BEN</div>` and your `CSS` class is ben so change class to `BEN` or change your div into `id="ben"`

This is first thing that you must check first whether you have correct classes in `HMTL` ad `CSS` file. `CSS` classes are `case-sensitive` so BEN it's not same with ben.

More [information](http://devedge-temp.mozilla.org/viewsource/2001/css-class-id/)

Here is more information about [CSS Mask-Image & Text](http://trentwalton.com/2011/05/19/mask-image-text/)

Comment: Thank you, but still I don't see image-mask working in jsfiddle or on my server